# Python 3.5 Factorial

Tags: python-3.x, factorial

```
i = input("Enter number", )
for i in range(i):
    i= i *(i+1)
    print(i)
```

I am trying to generate a factorial for any number the user inputs using the above code. How can I achieve this with the above code, without using the python factorial function. How I can also do it with the factorial function?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].  With sample input, show actual code and current/desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying `i` while iterating over it. Could you try:

```
i = int(input("Enter number", ))
f = 1
for j in range(i):
    f = f * (j+1)

print(f)
```

Comment: It gives the error message: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: I added a conversion of the input to int in my code

Answer (score 2):

you can do it recursively also in this way

```
def recur_factorial(n):
   """Function to return the factorial
   of a number using recursion"""
   if n == 1:
       return n
   else:
       return n*recur_factorial(n-1)

print recur_factorial(5)
```

You can take input from user in the form of  the integer and then pass in the factorial function

Answer (score 2):

use this function `math.factorial(value)` by importing `math` library in `python`.

Answer (score 0):

While using recursions you should use tail recursive functions like

```
def factorial2(x, fac):
   if x == 1:
     return fac
   else:
     return factorial2(x-1, x*fac)

factorial2(value_here,1)
```

You can use the built-in function with simple :

```
import math
math.factorial(value_here)
```

Comment: No need for the parentheses .

Comment: yes, but i always use when i can, for maybe its from math, but i really like things explicit

Comment: Sure, but it is bad Python style.

Comment: Its just a code example but yes, like i said i know, on software i use the style guides assigned to the project (mostly always pep 8 + google style) , and you only use () on if statements, according to pep 8, if the conditions space break lines, but the main point is still right